# SCRCPY: [server] ERROR: Could not invoke methodWARN: Device disconnected

Tags: android, shell, adb, mirror, fastboot

I'm encountering with an error message when attempting to use scrcpy.

I am trying to mirror the Android screen.
[Please refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l003z.png)

Error:
intel@intel-NUC12WSHi7:~$ scrcpy

INFO: scrcpy 1.12.1 https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy
/usr/share/scrcpy/scrcpy-server: 1 file pushed. 10.1 MB/s (24773 bytes in 0.002s)
INFO: Initial texture: 1920x1080
[server] ERROR: Exception on thread Thread[main,5,main]WARN: Device disconnected
intel@intel-NUC12WSHi7:~$

intel@intel-NUC12WSKi7:~$ scrcpy --version
scrcpy 1.12.1